# Rounding the corners of a DateField in Flex 4?

Tags: css, apache-flex, skinning, datefield

I'm using Flash builder, with flex 4 sdk and am trying to create a `DateField` in which the `TextInput` component has rounded corners.

I have tried the following code that doesn't work:

```
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" minWidth="1024" minHeight="768"
    xmlns:components="components.*">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";
        @namespace components "components.*";

        .roundedTI
        {
            corner-radius: 10;
            borderStyle: solid;   
        }

    </fx:Style>

    <mx:DateField textInputStyleName="roundedTI"/> 

</s:Application>
```

Can the community help me rectify any visible errors in my code or point me to a alternative guide or tutorial that demonstrates how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Flex 4, everything is in the Skins.  CSS is used largely just to apply one skin to a component or class of components, whereas in Flex 3 it was used to set tons of properties.  The cool thing is, however, that you can define any arbitrary style property value in CSS and it will be accessible via `getStyle` in the Skin!

As such, they don't have the `cornerRadius` property anymore.  Instead, you have to create a "DateFieldSkin", and apply it to your component via a css selector.  The default DateField skin uses the `DropDownSkin`.  Here's the code to solve this:

**DateFieldSkin**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>

    <!--- @private -->
    <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
        radiusX="{getStyle('cornerRadius')}" radiusY="{getStyle('cornerRadius')}">
        <s:stroke>          
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" color="0x5380D0" />
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <!--- @private -->
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="0xFFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Skin>
```

**Sample App**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
    minWidth="1024" minHeight="768">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        .roundedTI
        {
            corner-radius: 10;
            borderStyle: solid;
            borderSkin: ClassReference("DateFieldSkin");
        }

    </fx:Style>

    <mx:DateField textInputStyleName="roundedTI"/>

</s:Application>
```

You can also hardcode radius values into the skin, or do something even more dynamic and optimized.  This is just a start.

Let me know if that works,
Lance

Comment: thanks for the help.
I didn't know that skins that extend s:Skin can be used to skin Halo components